# How to make edit text hint label spannable

Tags: android, android-edittext, spannablestring

[image]I am creating a form dynamically. if hint text is large in length it gets cut and not appearing on next line.

```
SpannableString span = new SpannableString(fieldLabel);
span.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(0.8f), 0, fieldLabel.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
ed.setHint(span);
```

My Main layout is linear layout. 
What I am missing in the code.

Comment: it seems correct. Do you want to reduce the font size of the hint?

Comment: No Actually, If hint text length is more than single line then it should get come to next line.

Comment: It should work by default. Can u attach the XML file? Also the code that dynamically creates the form